# Why does United States gets article but not Japan?

Tags: articles

Why does the name " United States " gets article?

Like:

He is from Japan

He is from the United states

But Japan doesn't get article. Why?

Thanks

Comment: *She is from India, he is from the United Kingdom.* But *She is from the Republic of India, he is from Britain*. The same principle applies here, except that there is no English name for modern Japan which includes the type of state (it's not the *Empire of Japan*, even though there is an emperor, as that name refers to the prewar entity).

Answer (score 3):

The word "states" is not a proper noun.  It's essentially "those states [of America] that are now united" (add capitalization as desired).

Comment: I have searched and found it that it's best to call the countries by the name they have introduced themselves as to the English language.